# airflow worker docker container shuts down because of pid file

Tags: docker-compose, airflow, pid, vscode-devcontainer

I have an issue with starting my airflow development environment. I use a docker setup for airflow. When starting the airflow devcontainer in VSCode, the airflow_worker container stops working because of an existing pid file.

- VSCode Version: 1.72.1
- Dev Containers Version: v0.255.3
- Local OS Version: Windows Version 10.0.22000 Build 22000
- Remote OS Version: WSL Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
- Remote Extension/Connection Type: WSL/Containers

Logs inside the airflow worker container:

```
[2022-10-13 13:51:36 +0000] [33] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-10-13 13:51:36 +0000] [33] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8793 (33)
[2022-10-13 13:51:36 +0000] [33] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-10-13 13:51:36 +0000] [34] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 34
[2022-10-13 13:51:36 +0000] [35] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 35
[2022-10-13 13:51:39,155: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://airflow_redis:6379/0
[2022-10-13 13:51:39,166: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2022-10-13 13:51:40,199: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2022-10-13 13:51:40,219: INFO/MainProcess] celery@57982842b5a2 ready.
[2022-10-13 13:54:31 +0000] [34] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 34)
[2022-10-13 13:54:31 +0000] [35] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 35)

worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)
[2022-10-13 13:54:31 +0000] [33] [INFO] Handling signal: term

BACKEND=redis
DB_HOST=airflow_redis
DB_PORT=6379

 
 -------------- celery@57982842b5a2 v5.2.0 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5 2022-10-13 13:51:37
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         airflow.executors.celery_executor:0x7f2678761eb0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://airflow_redis:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     postgresql://airflow:**@airflow_postgres/airflow
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 16 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> default          exchange=default(direct) key=default
                

[tasks]
  . airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command


BACKEND=redis
DB_HOST=airflow_redis
DB_PORT=6379

[2022-10-13 13:56:11 +0000] [24] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-10-13 13:56:11 +0000] [24] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8793 (24)
[2022-10-13 13:56:11 +0000] [24] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-10-13 13:56:11 +0000] [25] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 25
[2022-10-13 13:56:11 +0000] [26] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 26
ERROR: Pidfile (/opt/airflow/airflow-worker.pid) already exists.
Seems we're already running? (pid: 7)
[2022-10-13 13:56:11 +0000] [24] [INFO] Handling signal: term
[2022-10-13 13:56:11 +0000] [26] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 26)
[2022-10-13 13:56:11 +0000] [25] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 25)
[2022-10-13 13:56:12 +0000] [24] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

What is happening here: First I freshly rebuilt the devcontainer and no problem occurs, then  closed the devcontainer, then reopened it again and that is when I get the error inside the airflow worker container (`ERROR: Pidfile (/opt/airflow/airflow-worker.pid) already exists. Seems we're already running? (pid: 7)`)

devcontainer.json

```json
{
    "name": "Airflow",
    "dockerComposeFile": "../../docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "airflow_webserver",
    "runServices": ["airflow_init", "airflow_webserver", "airflow_scheduler", "airflow_worker"],
    "remoteUser": "root",
    "workspaceFolder": "/opt/airflow",
    "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python",
        "eamodio.gitlens",
        "GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github",
        "njpwerner.autodocstring",
        "DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint"
    ],
    "settings": { 
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash",
        "python.pythonPath": "/var/lang/bin/python",
        "python.linting.enabled": true,
        "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
        "python.formatting.autopep8Path": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/autopep8",
        "python.formatting.blackPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/black",
        "python.formatting.yapfPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/yapf",
        "python.linting.banditPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/bandit",
        "python.linting.flake8Path": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/flake8",
        "python.linting.mypyPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/mypy",
        "python.linting.pycodestylePath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pycodestyle",
        "python.linting.pydocstylePath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pydocstyle",
        "python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pylint",
        "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
        "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
        "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
        "yaml.format.enable": true,
        "githubPullRequests.queries": [
            {
                "label": "Waiting For My Review",
                "query": "is:open review-requested:${user}"
            },
            {
                "label": "Assigned To Me",
                "query": "is:open assignee:${user}"
            },
            {
                "label": "Created By Me",
                "query": "is:open author:${user}"
            },
            {
                "label": "Mentioned Me",
                "query": "is:open mentions:${user}"
            }
        ],
        "githubIssues.queries": [
            {
                "label": "Current Iteration",
                "query": "project:company/2 assignee:${user} sort:created-desc label:current"
            }
        ]
    },
    "postAttachCommand": "sudo chmod o=rwx /var/run/docker.sock && git config core.filemode false",
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'

x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build:
    context: ./airflow/
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    args:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
      - PYPIPASS=${PYPIPASS}
      - PYPIUSER=${PYPIUSER}
      - AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.2.2
      - PYTHON_VERSION_SHORT=3.8
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@airflow_postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@airflow_postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@airflow_redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__ENABLE_XCOM_PICKLING: 'true' # https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13487
    AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__DEFAULT_UI_TIMEZONE: 'Europe/Berlin'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFAULT_TIMEZONE: 'Europe/Berlin'
    AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_CONFIG_CLASS: 'dags.settings.LOGGING_CONFIG'
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
    HOST_HOME: ${HOME}
    PYTHONPATH: '/opt/airflow'
    ENVIRONMENT: 'dev'
    USES_PYDOC: 'true'
  volumes:
    - ./airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./airflow/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./airflow/.git:/opt/airflow/.git
    - ./airflow/.gitignore:/opt/airflow/.gitignore
    - ./airflow/.gitmodules:/opt/airflow/.gitmodules
    - ./airflow/.devcontainer:/opt/airflow/.devcontainer
    - ./airflow/.docusaurus:/opt/airflow/.docusaurus
    - ./airflow/.docs:/opt/airflow/.docs
    - ./airflow/.circleci:/opt/airflow/.circleci
    - ./airflow/requirements.txt:/opt/airflow/requirements.txt
    - ./airflow/requirements_dev.txt:/opt/airflow/requirements_dev.txt
    - ./airflow/pydoc-markdown.yml:/opt/airflow/pydoc-markdown.yml
    - ./airflow/README.md:/opt/airflow/README.md
    - ./airflow/fargate_entrypoint.sh:/opt/airflow/fargate_entrypoint.sh
    - ./airflow/sync_dags.sh:/opt/airflow/sync_dags.sh
    - ./airflow/.vscode:/opt/airflow/.vscode
    - ./airflow/Dockerfile:/opt/airflow/Dockerfile
    - ./airflow/Dockerfile.dev:/opt/airflow/Dockerfile.dev
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - /tmp:/tmp # https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16803#issuecomment-874246604
  user: '$AIRFLOW_UID:$AIRFLOW_GID'
  networks:
    - localstack_nw
    - airflow_nw
  depends_on:
    airflow_redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    airflow_postgres:
      condition: service_healthy
    localstack:
      condition: service_started
    db:
      condition: service_started

services:
  db:
    container_name: company_db
    image: mdillon/postgis:10
    environment:
      - LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
      - LANG=C.UTF-8
      - POSTGRES_USER=company_master
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=8CGc4PpQT3lpd8sG4p5K
      - POSTGRES_DB=company
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    networks:
      - db_nw
      - db_pgadmin_nw
      - localstack_nw

  localstack:
    container_name: company_localstack
    image: localstack/localstack:0.14.3
    environment:
      LOCALSTACK_API_KEY: ${LOCALSTACK_API_KEY}
      DEBUG: 1
      # DATA_DIR: /tmp/localstack/data
      HOST_TMP_FOLDER: /tmp/localstack
      DOCKER_HOST: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      LAMBDA_EXECUTOR: docker-reuse
      LAMBDA_REMOTE_DOCKER: 0
      LAMBDA_STAY_OPEN_MODE: 0
      LAMBDA_DOCKER_FLAGS: -p 19891:19891
      LAMBDA_DOCKER_NETWORK: company_localstack_nw
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559"
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"
    volumes:
      - "/tmp/localstack:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "${HOME}/_company/company/services/qgis:${HOME}/_company/company/services/qgis"
    networks:
      - localstack_nw

  airflow_redis:
    container_name: company_airflow_redis
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "ping" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    networks:
      - airflow_nw

  airflow_postgres:
    container_name: company_airflow_postgres
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - airflowdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - airflow_nw
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow" ]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5

  airflow_webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    container_name: company_airflow_webserver
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 9080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD",
          "curl",
          "--fail",
          "http://localhost:8080/health"
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  airflow_init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-admin}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-company}

  airflow_scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    container_name: company_airflow_scheduler
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"'
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  airflow_worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    container_name: company_airflow_worker
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

volumes:
  dbdata: {}
  airflowdata: {}

networks:
  db_nw:
    driver: bridge
  db_pgadmin_nw:
    driver: bridge
  localstack_nw:
    driver: bridge
  mailhog_nw:
    driver: bridge
  airflow_nw:
    driver: bridge
```

To explain: The devcontainer is connected to the airflow_webserver service but also starts the other airflow services. For some reason, it is only the airflow_worker container that experiences the issue with the .pid file. My hunch is that when the devcontainer is closed, the airflow_worker container is not properly stopped. This issue does not happen when I start the containers with `docker-compose up` and close with `docker-compose down`. I previously looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37549262 to get the idea with `docker-compose down`. Thats when I realized the issue might lie with the devcontainer since it does not seem to execute `docker-compose down` when closing.

I would gladly recieve any help even just a hint in the right direction to solve this problem. Maybe someone had to deal with something similar in the past, especially similar problems with devcontainers and knows how to solve this. I also made an issue already: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7359.

Comment: thanks for posting - im hitting exact same issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I eventually found a satisfying solution by mounting the airflow_worker to a temporary file system. This way any files that are not mounted specifically under volumes are automatically deleted when closing the container. I just had to change two lines for the airflow_worker in the docker-compose.yml file.

```yaml
airflow_worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    # start
    tmpfs:
      - '/opt/airflow/'
    # end
    container_name: company_li_airflow_worker
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
```